# FDBK_Date function compile error "Method or data member not found" in MS Excel 365

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors, datepicker

I have Excel spreadsheets which use the FDBK_Date function.

Any time I click on the field containing that function, the debugger opens with the error message:

> "Compile error: Method or data member not found"

and then highlights the following section in the code in a window titled FDBK_DatePicker, highlighting the command `.MonthView1` below:

```
Sub FDBK_DatePicker()

    With XlocEntryCalendar
    .StartUpPosition = 0
    .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
    .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
    .MonthView1.Value = Date
    .Show
    End With
```

I used these Excel files for months, until a couple months back, when the error occurred.

I saw in a different post that mentioned the same error message for a different issue the suggestion to find any *.exd files on the hard drive and delete them, but trying that only lead to Excel not reacting to the first time the date picker cell is clicked and then creating a new version of the file MSForms.exd and then the error reappears as usual.

Comment: In the VBA Editor, check Tools, References. Any show up as "MISSING"?

Comment: @jkpieterse Thanks for the quick reply. I tried looking up the options you mentioned, but the References option is grayed out and not accessible.

Comment: Something's not adding up. That menu command is enabled whenever there's an active project in the VBE.

Comment: I managed to fix that. Turns out that as long as the debugger is active the References are not accessible. Save the project and reopen the macro window and the options works.
No option was listed as missing, but of all the listed references only 5 were ticked, 99% of them were inactive.

Comment: What is assigned to or what object is XlocEntryCalendar? It sounds as if it should contain a control called Monthview1, which is deleted.